# Add suffix to enum during runtime

Tags: c, enums

I want a function to accept an enum string and add a suffix to that string, essentially convert that into a define string.

ACTION_PERMIT ---> ACTION_PERMIT_F

Is there a way to do this?
Or is there a better way to perform this mapping?

```
typedef enum {
    ACTION_PERMIT,    
    ACTION_DENY,      
    ACTION_COUNT,     
    ACTION_TC,        
    ACTION_REDIRECT  
}action_e;

#define    ACTION_PERMIT_F        1 << 0     
#define    ACTION_DENY_F          1 << 1     
#define    ACTION_COUNT_F         1 << 2     
#define    ACTION_TC_F            1 << 3     
#define    ACTION_REDIRECT_F      1 << 4  


void rule_action_add(rule *rule, action_e action_type, uint32 value)
{
    assert(rule != NULL);
    action_t *action = &rule->action;

    action->exist_map |= action_type;   // <--- Use enum string and add "_F" suffix   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this?

Not like this. Value of `action_type` variable exists at runtime, and by that point preprocessor has already ran.

> Or is there a better way to perform this mapping?

You can use the numeric value of the enumeration constant for the bit shift.

```
action->exist_map |= (1u << action_type);
```